# Determine the distance from point $E$ to line $BC$, in cm

Tags: geometry

$ABCDE$ is a non-convex pentagon such that $\angle ABC=\angle ACD=\angle ADE={90}^{\circ}$

$AB=3$ cm, $BC=4$ cm, $CD=12$ cm and $DE=84$ cm

Determine the distance from point $E$ to line $BC$, in cm

Please help me out with this question. I tried calculating the angles using trigonometric functions, but it didn't work out. It will be beneficial. Thank you

---

My teacher gave me this problem. I tried working out the angles and rounded them to the nearest whole number. I calculated the rest of the sides as well. $AC=5,AD=13,AE=85$

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? What is your partial work on this problem?

Comment: My teacher gave me this problem. I tried working out the angles and rounded them to the nearest whole number. I calculated the rest of the sides as well. $AC=5$ , $AD=13$ , $AE=85$ all in cm

Comment: I already have a full answer typed out. I am waiting for you.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noticed, the pentagon can be decomposed into Pythagorean triangles. Assuming $A=(0,0)$, $B=(3,0)$ and $C=(3,4)$, the distance from $E$ to (the extension of) $BC$ is $3$ plus the horizontal displacement of $E$ from the origin:
$$3-85\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\frac43+\tan^{-1}\frac{12}5+\tan^{-1}\frac{84}{13}\right)=\frac{5328}{65}$$
Here we use the arctangent addition formula
$$\tan^{-1}a+\tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}\frac{a+b}{1-ab}$$
but beware of the combined angle being more than a half-turn!

Comment: Thank you helped a lot